# Having an issue subsetting a data frame by a factor variable in R

Tags: r

- I am trying to subset my data frame (train) by the factor variable $area__rucc into two groups: metro and non-metro. This data Frame is clean, has 34 variables, and 2,811 observations.

  ```
   glimpse(train$area__rucc)
  ```

  Factor w/ 9 levels "Metro - Counties in metro areas of 1 million population or more",..: 3 3 1 6 7 8 6 2 7 5 ...

The first three levels indicate metro, the last six indicate non-metro

**- First I tried to subset by metro...**

```
metro <- subset(train, area__rucc == c("Metro - Counties in metro areas of 1 million population or more", "Metro - Counties in metro areas of 250,000 to 1 million population", "Metro - Counties in metro areas of fewer than 250,000 population"))
```

This seemed to work as intended and returned a df with 387 observations.

**- Next I attempted to subset by the non-metro levels like this...**

```
not_metro <- subset(train, area__rucc != c("Metro - Counties in metro areas of 1 million population or more", "Metro - Counties in metro areas of 250,000 to 1 million population", "Metro - Counties in metro areas of fewer than 250,000 population"))
```

This returned 2811 observations, but upon further inspection the df contained metro levels as well as non-metro levels. Obviously not working as I intended.

**- My third shot...**

```
non_metro <- subset(train, area__rucc == c("Nonmetro - Completely rural or less than 2,500 urban population, adjacent to a metro area", 
                "Nonmetro - Completely rural or less than 2,500 urban population, not adjacent to a metro area", 
                "Nonmetro - Urban population of 2,500 to 19,999, adjacent to a metro area", 
                "Nonmetro - Urban population of 2,500 to 19,999, not adjacent to a metro area", 
                "Nonmetro - Urban population of 20,000 or more, adjacent to a metro area", 
                "Nonmetro - Urban population of 20,000 or more, not adjacent to a metro area"))
```

Here I explicitly listed the non-metro levels (4:9). This returned a df with 354 observations all of which are non-metro.

387 (metro) + 354 (non-metro) != 3189
There are no missing values in train$area_rucc, so the two df's I am trying to create from train should hold the same amount of observations as the original df, correct?

I have a feeling I am making a silly mistake that I can't seem to catch right now (lack of experience, probably) or maybe I am just completely off base with what i am trying to do here, but this is starting to frustrate me, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `==` does pair-wise (rowwise) comparison. You want to use `%in%` instead. Compare `1:4 == c(2, 3)` vs `1:4 %in% c(2, 3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`==` does element-wise (row-wise) comparison - you want `%in%` instead

Let's do a simple example before we get to your code

```
x = 1:6
y = c(1, 3)
x == y
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Notice how there is only one `TRUE`, even though 1 and 3 are both in `1:6`. That's because the comparison is happening like this:

```
data.frame(x, y, "x==y" = x == y, check.names = FALSE)
#   x y  x==y
# 1 1 1  TRUE   # 1 does equal 1
# 2 2 3 FALSE   # 2 does not equal 3
# 3 3 1 FALSE   # 3 does not equal 1
# 4 4 3 FALSE   # 4 does not equal 3
# 5 5 1 FALSE   # 5 does not equal 1
# 6 6 3 FALSE   # 6 does not equal 3
```

`x == y` checks the first element of `x` against the first of `y`, the second of `x` against the second of `y`, etc. If one of `x` or `y` is shorter, it will be "recycled", like you can see in the data frame above where the input `y = c(1, 3)` becomes `1 3 1 3 1 3` in the data frame.

Instead, use `%in%`:

```
x %in% y
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

`x %in% y` check each element of `x` against all elements of `y`. Now we get two TRUE values, because both 1 and 3 are **in** `c(1, 3)`

---

Applied to your problem:

```
metro <- subset(train,
    area__rucc %in% c(
        "Metro - Counties in metro areas of 1 million population or more",
        "Metro - Counties in metro areas of 250,000 to 1 million population",
        "Metro - Counties in metro areas of fewer than 250,000 population"
    )
)
```

And you can negate it to, `! x %in% y`, so

```
not_metro <- subset(train,
        !area__rucc %in% c(
            "Metro - Counties in metro areas of 1 million population or more",
            "Metro - Counties in metro areas of 250,000 to 1 million population",
            "Metro - Counties in metro areas of fewer than 250,000 population"
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what end result you are going for, I'm thinking something tidy like this should work:

```
    train %>%
        mutate(metro = ifelse(area__rucc=="Metro - Counties in metro areas of 1 million population or more"|area__rucc=="Metro - Counties in metro areas of 250,000 to 1 million population",area__rucc("Metro - Counties in metro areas of fewer than 250,000 population",1,0) %>%
        group_by(metro)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into the guts of your dataframe, I think the following toy example might help you.

```
alphab <- data.frame(letters = c("A","T", "U", "Z"))
alphab

consonants <- subset(alphab, letters %in% c("T", "Z"))
consonants

vowels <- subset(alphab, !(letters %in% c("T","Z")))
vowels
```